# Separate table for banned users?

Tags: mysql, sql

What would be the "correct" way of organizing banned users?

Should I simply add a new column in the existing `users` table called `is_banned` that acts as a boolean or should I create a new table called `banned_users` that acts as a pivot table with the `user_id`?

The same question goes for administrators. Should I create a new table for site admins or just create a new column called `is_admin`?

What about performance of the two options?

Thanks.

Comment: keep em in the same table. bad security on 2 = bad security on 1. when you have performance problems on your user table, you have a good problem to have

Comment: It depends on the no of users. I would go for same table with adding columns to identify the access n same applies to admins.

Comment: Table for users, table for roles and junction table that connects users to roles. You can have a role of a `peon`, `admin` and `banned`. If you add `banned` to the junction table `user2roles`, then it becomes easy to add roles, behaviours for the roles and you separated your user data from their respective roles since you established relations - which is what relational databases are for. As for performance, you don't solve performance by cutting down some small numbers.

Comment: how about non-users that engage in sql injection. how do you ban them?

Answer (score 4):

What happens with the next type of users - add another table? Better not.

You could add a new column called `type` or something like that. One way would be it containing a number indicating the type like

```
1 = normal user
2 = admin
3 = banned
```

or you could even add another table called `user_types` that refer to it, but that would only be necessary if you have the types changing over time.

If you need to combine types - users having multiple types at once, then you could make the column a bit field.

#### When do you need seperate tables?

When these different users would have different attributes and the tables for each type of users would differ.

Comment: What about banned admins?

Comment: If a user is banned it does not matter if he was an admin in the past IMO

Comment: Works fine till you add power users, and now you don't know whether a banned user was normal or power.

Comment: Then make the column a bit field

Comment: What if it's a 2 week ban?

Comment: Anyway, picking nits here. +1 for correct answer of "add column(s), not tables".

Comment: @Blorgbeard it's not the correct answer, it's one of two valid answers whose correctness depends on context. Your 2w ban is a perfect example of why a table might actually be the better choice.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Why does a bit field not work with a 2 week ban and does with a new table?

Comment: @juergend bit fields suck. They're more difficult to work with, more fragile (might need to add bits for one component if it goes up from 2^n-1 states), and require app code to use magic numbers to mask bits instead of nice human-readable names.

Comment: Then use multiple bool/bit columns. IsAdmin, IsBanned, etc. Multiple tables is not the correct solution.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Well I disagree, but let us not get into that :)

Comment: @Blorgbeard your own 2w ban example shows why a table may be the better choice. What if you want to record who banned them, why, when, a list complainants (a third table!), an audit trail of this and earlier banning incidents? Real life is almost never as simple as a Boolean. The extra columns mindset leads to massively bloated tables that perform poorly for all queries. A well thought out design considers numerous factors and makes an informed decision in context. It doesn't just assume that "add columns" is the only possible answer.

Comment: Adding more tables for more entities is fine. I'm saying duplicating the users table into an identical (or worse, *slightly* different) bannedUsers table is the wrong solution.

Comment: @Blorgbeard agreed, though I'm not sure juergend ever intended that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to think about how the banning concept will play out in the real world. Do you just want a flag? What about when they were banned and by whom? past banning history? a response mechanism for the banned? A list of complaints, with user/date/reason?

Data models are the most difficult part of a system to evolve, so you want to think about all manner of possible futures, even stuff you don't have on the roadmap just yet.

You might decide, for efficiency, that you want a ban table and a banned column. But there's a price to be paid for that too, since you're now capturing the same fact in multiple places.

The issues are subtle and sometimes complex. Don't accept blanket one-size-fits-all answers.

Comment: How does this answer the question? A bunch of "what ifs", classic programming story where scenarios are invented for the sake of it. At best, this should be a comment, you didn't help at all.

Comment: @N.B. Why do you say, "invented for the sake of it"? These kinds of scenarios play out in real-world systems all the time.

Comment: Because you came up with scenarios that are not contained in the original question. By the same logic, we could do this for every single question on SO and never be done with solving the problem. You apparently have or had experience with similar systems, but the OP hasn't shared a single thing about his app logic - you invented scenarios for him and started to propose problems. I honestly don't see how that solves the original problem, nor do I see a single useful line of code in your "answer". The inventing game can be played by anyone, and I don't see any solutions in what you wrote.

Comment: @N.B. Asking a few questions along the lines of "have you considered…?" is often exactly what someone wants/needs. I perceived in this case that maybe the OP needed a bit of prompting. I'm not going refrain from offering insights just because they might not be useful.

Comment: You see, I never said your insights were *wrong* or not useful. I just said you posed **problems** but offered no **solutions**. You can also see I didn't downvote you. What bothers me is that you have a scenario with a problem but no solution posted whatsoever, you just added oil to the fire. Is the OP supposed to ask a question for each of your insights? TL;DR: add a potential solution to each of your insights.

Comment: @N.B. The OP didn't give me the impression that they need their hand held with the design. They just wanted to know which way they should go. You may disagree, and (as you've done) are perfectly entitled to answer according to your interpretation of the OP's request, but that's not how I read the question.

Answer (score 2):

The scalable solution that satisfies multitude of criteria would be this:

- table that contains user data, `users`
- table that contains roles - `roles`
- junction table that connects the two, `user2roles`

You keep the user data separate from their actual role in your app - every user will at least have name and last name, those are not related to their permissions or roles.

You will most likely need to add more roles. For example, one role is being an `admin`. Another role is being banned. Another role can be being banned for a week, 2 weeks etc - basically you can add those as you go, without needing to alter your tables to support future functionality.

Your application (php, python, whatever) collects the data and then acts upon those roles.

Now you have a system that's got established relations, that you can scale and that's easy to understand by kids in kindergarden.

This is a simplified system that mixes permissions with roles, you can further expand it but IMO it's better to keep it simple.